# duda en como crear valores por defecto en un objeto de javaScript

Tags: javascript

En el ejercicio me piden que cree un objeto llamado user con argumentos llamados: username y status. en el argumento de username puedo colocar cualquier string, en el argumento de status me pide que coloque como valor : away. Después me pide que haga una función llamada loginEvent en la cual cambie el status away por status: active.
y que regrese ' "your_username is active'.

yo intenté colocar esto:

```
const user= {
    username :'jesus',
    status : 'away'
};
const loginEvent =({username, status = 'active'})=>{
    return (`your ${username} is ${status}`);
};

loginEvent(user);
```

Pero al correrlo obviamente el status me sigue saliendo como away. Qué debo hacer para que salga 'active'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo debes invertir los valores. En la función el valor por defecto será `away` y en el objeto el valor será `active`:

```js
const user = {
    username :'jesus',
    status : 'active'
};
const loginEvent = ({username, status = 'away' })=> {
    return (`your ${username} is ${status}`);
};

console.log(loginEvent(user))
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que te están pidiendo es algo como:

```js
class User {

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.status = 'away'; // todos los user son creados con status 'away'
  }
}

function loginEvent(user) {
  user.status = 'active';
  return `${user.name} is ${user.status}`;
}

const user = new User('Juan');
console.log('Valor inicial:', JSON.stringify(user));
console.log(loginEvent(user));
console.log('Valor tras el "log in":', JSON.stringify(user));
```

Comment: ese ejemplo que me estas colocando lo han puesto para ejercicios de temas posteriores y también me han funcionado, gracias.